# How to simply this 2 to 1 mux boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra, multiplexer

I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html) for a 2 to 1 mux.
They create this circuit:
[image]

They then derive this boolean algebra expression and simplification:
[image]

I'm confused how they made the simplification though.  I see that the expression can be simplified to \$I_0*I_1 * (\overline{A} + A)\$ by simplifying the double negatives, but I don't see how they got any farther than that

Comment: Do you know about *Karnaugh maps*? If not, google that.

Comment: Another way to arrive at that final formula is to look at the circuit. The final NAND has all its inputs and outputs inverted, so you can replace it (and all the inversions) by an OR. That's the + in your final formula. The two items that are added are A*I1 and not(A)*I2, so there you are.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I don't understand what you're saying.  What do you mean you can just replace the final NAND and it's inputs with an OR?  Wouldn't that give not NOT(I0&A) OR NOT (NOT A& I1)?

Comment: A or B == not( not( A ) AND not( b ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a slightly different notation/symbols to denote it easier:

- a = not A
- A = A
- b = not I1
- B = I1
- c = not I0
- C = I0

> ```
> Q = aBc + aBC + AbC + ABC   
>   = aB(c + C) + AC(b + B)     // c + C = true, aB(true) = aB
>                               // b + B = true, AC(true) = AC
>   = aB        + AC
> ```

Written back in original symbols:

> Q = aB         + AC
>          = not(A) * I1 + A * I0